# What's to know about pre-set keywords like :refer, :use and :only in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, metadata

We use special keywords such as `:refer`, `:as`, `:only` and others, in namespacing.

What are those keywords called? The books I've seen so far simply refer to them as themselves, except for The Joy of Clojure which seems to call them "directives" on page 199.

Clojure.org calls them ["metadata keys," under "special forms"](http://clojure.org/special_forms) when they relate to vars. Somehow those docs don't seem to be telling the whole story (or at least I'm not really getting it), and maybe I'm confusing a different kind of key? Vars have "metadata keys" like `:doc` and `:name`, whereas using `:refer` to control namespacing seems to *do* something. Are these both the same types?

I'm referring to words preceded by colons, like regular keywords, but which have special purposes in Clojure.

What should we know about them? Keywords? Directives, whatever that means? Metadata keywords?

And, if all vars have metadata keys, can we access them like we can with JavaScript vars, prototypes, etc., in a browser console, for example?

As you may have guessed, a Clojure beginner here...
Thanks.

Comment: Meta data is map with some data that doesn't affect the actual data but describes it in someway. When compiler compiles a code it refer to that metadata map and if there are some keys like :private :doc e.t.c it perform some additional action. There is, however, special syntax defined to make it easier to type. You can store in metadata whatever you want. For example zippers store there functions to operate the tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to distinguish what they *are* and what they *mean*.

Keywords are just symbolic identifiers that evaluate to themselves.

Depending on the *context*, they can have different purposes. You can define your own function where keywords mean something special for you. Clojure has different contexts where keywords serve a very specific role, as the one you write about in your question. The specific names *metadata keys* refer to a particular role attributed to a set of known keywords in a specific case.

Symbols and collections (not variables) can be bound to metadata (like symbol properties in CL). You can access this metadata simply by calling `(meta s)` for a symbol `s`. See the documentation for [metadata](http://clojure.org/metadata).

Answer (score 1):

In short, nothing.  Keywords are keywords, functions are functions, and macros are macros.

`ns` is merely a macro.  As you can see in [the source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/bdc752a7fefff5e63e0847836ae5e6d95f971c37/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5529), it expands to expressions that loads references into the Clojure runtime.  `:refer`, `:use`, and `:only` are simply the keywords those functions happen to use.   You could copy that code and make your own `my-ns` macro that uses different keywords, and it would work exactly the same.